# What are the properties of a "non-participating editor" in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

The eclipse documentation says that the method

```
IWorkbenchPage.hideEditor(IEditorReference ref)
```

will "remove an open editor, turn it into a non-participating editor". But what does *non-participating* mean? Is the plugin still running in the background? Is it still possible to programmatically access the EditorPart of the hidden editor in another plugin?

If I had a GEF editor and would hide it using hideEditor(), would it still be possible to render an overview of the diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Eclipse Kepler implementation of `IWorkbenchPage` the `hideEditor` method does nothing except logging an unsupported message if debugging is enabled.

Comment: Hm that is not very useful :) Is there a built in way to hide an editor and have the plugin still running in the background or do I need to implement it myself (like http://www.niallkelly.com/?p=13)?

Comment: I would use a separate plugin that provided an OSGi service to do the background work. Then it does not matter if the editor is visible or not.

Comment: My problem is that i would like to hide the gef editor, but its miniature view should still be visible. That is only possible if the editor is still running or am I wrong?